# docker revert changes to container

Tags: import, load, save, export, docker

I'm trying to snapshot my docker container so that I can revert back to a single point in time.

I've looked at `docker save` and `docker export` but neither of these seems to do what I'm looking for. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 10):

You might want to use [docker commit](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#commit). This command will create a new *docker image* from one of your *docker containers*. This way you can easily create a new container later on based on that new image.

Be aware that the `docker commit` command won't save any data stored in Docker [data volumes](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/). For those you need to make [backups](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes).

---

For instance if you are working with the following Dockerfile which declares a volume and will write the date every 5 seconds to two files (one being in the volume, the other not):

```
FROM base
VOLUME /data
CMD while true; do date >> /data/foo.txt; date >> /tmp/bar.txt; sleep 5; done
```

Build a image from it:

```
$ docker build --force-rm -t so-26323286 .
```

and run a new container from it:

```
$ docker run -d so-26323286
```

Wait a bit so that the running docker container have a chance to write the date to the two files a couple of times.

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
07b094be1bb2        so-26323286:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'while t   5 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds                            agitated_lovelace
```

Then commit your container into a new image `so-26323286:snapshot1`:

```
$ docker commit agitated_lovelace so-26323286:snapshot1
```

You can now see that you have two images availables:

```
$ docker images | grep so-26323286
so-26323286                    snapshot1           03180a816db8        19 seconds ago      175.3 MB
so-26323286                    latest              4ffd141d7d6f        9 minutes ago       175.3 MB
```

Now let's verify that a new container run from `so-26323286:snapshot1` would have the `/tmp/bar.txt` file:

```
$ docker run --rm so-26323286:snapshot1 cat /tmp/bar.txt
Sun Oct 12 09:00:21 UTC 2014
Sun Oct 12 09:00:26 UTC 2014
Sun Oct 12 09:00:31 UTC 2014
Sun Oct 12 09:00:36 UTC 2014
Sun Oct 12 09:00:41 UTC 2014
Sun Oct 12 09:00:46 UTC 2014
Sun Oct 12 09:00:51 UTC 2014
```

And witness that such a container does not have any `/data/foo.txt` file (as `/data` is a data volume):

```
$ docker run --rm so-26323286:snapshot1 cat /data/foo.txt
cat: /data/foo.txt: No such file or directory
```

Finally if you want to access to the `/data/foo.txt` file which is in the first (still running) container, you can use the docker run `--volumes-from` option:

```
$ docker run --rm --volumes-from agitated_lovelace base cat /data/foo.txt
Sun Oct 12 09:00:21 UTC 2014
Sun Oct 12 09:00:26 UTC 2014
Sun Oct 12 09:00:31 UTC 2014
Sun Oct 12 09:00:36 UTC 2014
Sun Oct 12 09:00:41 UTC 2014
Sun Oct 12 09:00:46 UTC 2014
Sun Oct 12 09:00:51 UTC 2014
Sun Oct 12 09:00:56 UTC 2014
Sun Oct 12 09:01:01 UTC 2014
Sun Oct 12 09:01:06 UTC 2014
Sun Oct 12 09:01:11 UTC 2014
Sun Oct 12 09:01:16 UTC 2014
```

Comment: docker commit doesn't seem to do what I want it to do. I have a wordpress image. When I add a post and do docker commit, and then start an new container with my new image, the new posts are missing. I feel like docker has a different idea of committment then the rest of the world.

Comment: you should study the Dockerfile for that wordpress image to discover if it uses volumes to store the post data. Also that wordpress container might rely on a second database container to store its data, if that is your case then you want to save the database container, not the wordpress container.

Comment: No, it's all self-contained, so I can't figure out why the data doesn't persist.

Comment: Maybe you could share the WordPress Docker file

Comment: here you are: the `tutum/wordpress` image is based on the [tutum/lamp](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/tutum/lamp/dockerfile/) image which defines the following volumes: `VOLUME  ["/etc/mysql", "/var/lib/mysql" ]`. the volume `/var/lib/mysql` holds the database data and thus your posts

Comment: What does that mean exactly? And specifically in terms of me getting the data to persist?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62935/discussion-between-thomas-and-pguardiario).

Comment: So I need to update my dockerfile and remove the volumes and my data will then persist?

Comment: Or you could just back up that volume, take a snapshot of your mysql database.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to do it with the `hello-world` image from Docker Hub

First run the hello-world image, thereby downloading the image:

```
docker run hello-world
```

Then get the hash of the image you want to get the has of

```
docker history hello-world
```

You will see something like:

```
IMAGE               CREATED
fce289e99eb9        15 months ago
```

`fce289e99eb9` is your hash-code.

To tag this image, you run:

```
docker tag fce289e99eb9 hello-world:SNAPSHOT-1.0
```

To list all the tags for a repository, use:

```
docker image ls hello-world
```

And you will get something like:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED    SIZE 
hello-world         SNAPSHOT-1.0        fce289e99eb9        15 months ago       1.84kB 
hello-world         latest              fce289e99eb9        15 months ago       1.84kB
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.
It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also Explaining entirely code-based answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers

Comment: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dasgoll/476ecc7a057ac885f0be/raw/cea88aefef51db1b7cfa0a8a9aca696def1a65b8/docker%2520rollback%2520image%2520changes